# Inputbox with button next to it shortens the width of the Inputbox width SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am adding a `flexbox` in a `simpleform` dynamically. The `flexbox` items contains inputbox and two buttons (in the same line). This is reducing the width of the inputbox.

When I try to increase the width of the inputbox, it is being covered by the buttons (the buttons are not moving next to the box after increasing the width). I want them in the same line, with inputbox width to be long enough.

Here is my XML structure:

```
<Panel setVisible="true">
            <f:SimpleForm id="site" 
                editable="true"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                singleContainerFullSize="true"
                labelSpanXL="3"
                labelSpanL="3"
                labelSpanM="3"
                labelSpanS="3"
                emptySpanXL="2"
                emptySpanL="2"
                emptySpanM="2"
                emptySpanS="2">
                <f:content>
                    <Label text="site" required="true" />
                        <l:VerticalLayout id="VLayout">
                        </l:VerticalLayout>
```

I'm adding the flexbox to the Vertical Layout dynamically on load of the fragment:

```
var addIcon = new sap.m.Button({
  id: "addB",
  icon: "sap-icon://sys-add",
  type: "Transparent"
});
var oInput = new sap.m.Input();
var inputBox = new sap.m.FlexBox({
  alignItems: "Center",
  justifyContent: "Start",
});
this.getView().byId("VLayout").addContent(inputBox);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place icon next to or within input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024719/how-to-place-icon-next-to-or-within-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GridData` with `span` of `sap.ui.layout` to achieve it. Give the `span` for the input.