# How to place icon next to or within input field

Tags: sapui5

How I can put my icon next to or within the input field?
[image]

The problem is, the icon changes the form. Usually, it's like this:
[image]

But when I'm adding the icon (code below), it displaces the *Dauer* input Field.

Is there a way to make it look clean and that's next to it? Or better in the input field inside?

I can make the button smaller with CSS but there is still a gap between them.. And it does not move automatically.

The best solution is like the *Datum* above with a small icon inside where I can click or like the icon is next to the Dauer without no gap between input field from Dauer and the `?` icon.

PS: I just want it like this (I will decide then later which option is better. But it is possible?)
[image]

```xml
<form:SimpleForm id="neuezeiterfassung"
  editable="true"
  title="Neue Zeiterfassung anlegen"
>
  <Label
    text="Auftrag"
    class="font1"
    tooltip="Auftrag eingeben"
  />
  <l:VerticalLayout>
    <ComboBox id="Auftrag"
      items="{/ZAUFKSet}"
      showSecondaryValues="true"
      width="50%"
    >
      <core:ListItem text="{Aufnr}" />
    </ComboBox>
  </l:VerticalLayout>
  <Label
    text="Datum"
    class="font1"
  />
  <DatePicker id="DP3"
    valueFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"
    displayFormat="medium"
    width="50%"
    placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"
  />
  <Label class="font1" text="Dauer" />
  <Input id="dauer"
    class="dauer"
    placeholder="Dauer eingeben ... "
    width="50%"
  />
  <HBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
    <core:Icon
      src="sap-icon://sys-help"
      class="size1" color="#031E48" press="aseads"
    >
      <core:layoutData>
        <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
      </core:layoutData>
    </core:Icon>
  </HBox>
  <!-- <Button icon="sap-icon://sys-help"  class="myButton"/> -->
  <Label class="font1" text="Arbeitsbeschreibung" />
  <TextArea id="beschreibung" width="50%" />
</form:SimpleForm>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** with the change in [commit:`8f1757d`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/8f1757d698e47a7d647908ca642d10fccabae058), which is available since UI5 1.84, the *value help icon* can be changed via `valueHelpIconSrc`:

```xml
<Input showValueHelp="true"
  valueHelpIconSrc="sap-icon://sys-help"
  valueHelpRequest="alert('Help requested')"
/><!-- valueHelpIconSrc available since 1.84.0 -->
```

No need to extend `sap.m.InputBase` in this case. Other input controls like `sap.m.MaskInput` still need to be extended as shown in the linked Plunk below.

---

**Original answer:**

> The best solution is like the *Datum* above with a small icon inside where I can click. (...) Is it possible?

Yes, it's possible. Here is a **minimal example:** https://embed.plnkr.co/EzlF2tkvalJWvSEn

[image: Extended sap.m.InputBase]

For this, UI5 provides the API `addEndIcon`<sup>[api](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/methods/addEndIcon)</sup> which is protected, meaning it should be used **only when extending `sap.m.InputBase`!**

As an argument for the `addEndIcon`, you can pass a map of settings that are required to create  `sap.ui.core.Icon`<sup>[api](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Icon)</sup>, which is highly customizable.

```js
const icon = this.addEndIcon({
  id: this.getId() + "-questionMarkBtn",
  src: IconPool.getIconURI("sys-help"),
  noTabStop: true,
  tooltip: "Information",
  press: [this.onEndButtonPress, this],
}); // See sap.ui.core.Icon/properties for more settings
// icon.addStyleClass(...); if even more customization required..
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using the below code, just updated the CSS as per your requirement. It is a responsive design, it will work for all the devices.

**CODE**

```
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <f:SimpleForm 
                editable="true"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                title="Neue Zeiterfassung anlegen"
                labelSpanXL="3"
                labelSpanL="3"
                labelSpanM="3"
                labelSpanS="12"
                adjustLabelSpan="false"
                emptySpanXL="1"
                emptySpanL="1"
                emptySpanM="1"
                emptySpanS="0"
                columnsXL="1"
                columnsL="1"
                columnsM="1"
                singleContainerFullSize="false" >
            <f:content>
                <Label text="Auftrag" tooltip="Auftrag eingeben" />
                <ComboBox items="{/ZAUFKSet}" id="Auftrag" showSecondaryValues="true">
                    <core:ListItem text="{Aufnr}"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <Label text="Datum" labelFor="DP3"/>
                <DatePicker id="DP3" valueFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" displayFormat="medium" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"/>
                <Label class="font1" text="Dauer"/>
                <Input value="Street">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="XL7 L7 M7 S10" />
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Button icon="sap-icon://sys-help"  press="onPress" >
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="XL1 L1 M1 S2" />
                    </layoutData>
                </Button>
                <Label text="Arbeitsbeschreibung"/>
                <TextArea id="beschreibung"/>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </VBox>
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you are looking for below output

[image]

```
<f:SimpleForm 
    editable="true"
    layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
    title="Neue Zeiterfassung anlegen"
    labelSpanXL="3"
    labelSpanL="3"
    labelSpanM="3"
    labelSpanS="12"
    adjustLabelSpan="false"
    emptySpanXL="1"
    emptySpanL="1"
    emptySpanM="1"
    emptySpanS="0"
    columnsXL="1"
    columnsL="1"
    columnsM="1"
    singleContainerFullSize="false" >
    <f:content>
    <Label text="Auftrag" tooltip="Auftrag eingeben" />
      <ComboBox items="{/ZAUFKSet}" id="Auftrag" showSecondaryValues="true">
        <core:ListItem text="{Aufnr}"/>
          <layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="XL8 L8 M7 S9" />
          </layoutData>
      </ComboBox>
        <Label text="Datum" labelFor="DP3"/>
        <DatePicker id="DP3" valueFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" displayFormat="medium" 
         placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
         <layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="XL8 L8 M7 S9" />
         </layoutData>
            </DatePicker>
             <Label class="font1" text="Dauer"/>
                <Input value="Street">
        <layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="XL8 L8 M7 S9" />
        </layoutData>
            </Input>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://sys-help"  press="onPress" width="40px" >
        <layoutData>
            <l:GridData span="XL1 L1 M1 S3" />
                </layoutData>
                    </Button>
                    <Label text="Arbeitsbeschreibung"/>
                    <TextArea id="beschreibung">
                        <layoutData>
                            <l:GridData span="XL8 L8 M7 S9" />
                        </layoutData>
                    </TextArea>
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
```

With icon

```
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
    <f:SimpleForm 
        editable="true"
        layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
        title="Neue Zeiterfassung anlegen"
        labelSpanXL="3"
        labelSpanL="3"
        labelSpanM="3"
        labelSpanS="12"
        adjustLabelSpan="false"
        emptySpanXL="1"
        emptySpanL="1"
        emptySpanM="1"
        emptySpanS="0"
        columnsXL="1"
        columnsL="1"
        columnsM="1"
        singleContainerFullSize="false" >
        <f:content>
            <Label text="Auftrag" tooltip="Auftrag eingeben" />
            <ComboBox items="{/ZAUFKSet}" id="Auftrag" showSecondaryValues="true">
                <core:ListItem text="{Aufnr}"/>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="XL10 L10 M10 S10" />
                </layoutData>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label text="Datum" labelFor="DP3"/>
            <DatePicker id="DP3" valueFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" displayFormat="medium" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="XL10 L10 M10 S10" />
                </layoutData>
            </DatePicker>
            <Label class="font1" text="Dauer"/>
            <Input value="Street">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="XL10 L10 M10 S10" />
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <HBox>
                <core:Icon src="sap-icon://sys-help" color="#031E48" press="onPress" class="infoIcon"/>
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="XL1 L1 M1 S1" />
                </layoutData>
            </HBox>
            <Label text="Arbeitsbeschreibung"/>
            <TextArea id="beschreibung">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="XL10 L10 M10 S10" />
                </layoutData>
            </TextArea>
        </f:content>
    </f:SimpleForm>
</VBox>
```

If you are using the ICON you need to add the style as well for alignment

```
.infoIcon {
  line-height: 3rem;
}
```

Comment: THANKS! yeah the smart form thing.. i dont really get.. i try it like you but the thing with labelspanXL and and.. i just dont get it why and when. 
I done it also with css.. BUUUT it is not really responsive.. i got a icon and 
make it like this: `#__hbox0-cont0_1{
 margin-left: -16% !important; 
}` but it is not responsive.. i try a bit around.. dont get it to work. Maybe you know smthing? If i make my windows smaller its move away from where i place it.

Comment: I am not using smart form, it is `SimpleForm` only. I am just using the `layoutData` with `l:GridData ` to achieve the functionality. You can go through the [samples](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleForm354/preview) and click edit icon. What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I have added a new screenshot and updated the code, hope you are look for the same solution.

Comment: aaah thanks.. i though it is smartform.. i gone try it.. and play around a bit.. maybe you can explain in your own word what labelSpanXl, labelspanL... empty.. and so on does? i dont really get it. because you use the `l:GirdData span..` where you set your data.. and i dont really understand it.And also i use `<core:Icon`instead of a button but it should work like this. I really appriciate your time and help

Comment: I have updated my code for Icon as well, kindly check it out. When It comes to `labelspanL` means - what will be the Labels span for the Large devices. Same applies to `XL` - Extra Large, `M` - Medium & `S` - Small devices. If you have observe the output for different sizes, in small devices the label will be shown in complete row. It is because of  `labelSpanS="12"`. Each row will have 12 spans, you are just managing the spans so that the elements should adjust based on the device sizes. So the layout will be responsive.

Comment: thanks you are the best :*, really thanks. if i move the icon with css it is still responsive?

Comment: Yes it will be, I have style the icon as well

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes extending the [InputBase](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/) class can be a bit overkill/increase the complexity of the code.

You can also use [Flexbox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FlexBox) containers to achieve the alignment of the input and the icon.

For example, if you want the input and the icon to be centered vertically and horizontally:

```xml
<HBox
    alignItems="Center"
    justifyContent="Center">
    <Input>
        <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="3" />
        </layoutData>
    </Input>
    <core:Icon
            src="sap-icon://sys-help">
        <!-- Be careful here with the namespaces (use layoutData from core, not m) -->
        <core:layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
        </core:layoutData>
    </core:Icon>
</HBox>
```

This will give something like this:

[image: example of input and icon alignment]

See [Flexbox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.FlexBox/sample/sap.m.sample.FlexBoxBasicAlignment) for more examples (API Reference is available at the top of the page).